# Determining the region from several sources of information

Tags: c#, .net

The task is to determine the region by comparing three sources of information taking into account the coefficients of their importance.

```
//GetRegionIdByKeywordAsync returns region id by string name, if the region could not be determined, 0 will return

//The received identifiers can completely or partially coincide, or be absolutely different
int regionIdByIp = await GetRegionIdByKeywordAsync(regionByIpStr);
int regionIdByPhone = await GetRegionIdByKeywordAsync(regionByPhoneStr);
int regionIdByInput = await GetRegionIdByKeywordAsync(regionByInputStr);

var weights = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>
{
  //Each source of information has its own importance coefficient, determined manually
  new KeyValuePair<int, int>(regionIdByIp, 5),
  new KeyValuePair<int, int>(regionIdByPhone, 3),
  new KeyValuePair<int, int>(regionIdByInput, 4)
};

//The final decision is determined by the search for a region that has the highest score in the total
int regionId = weights.Where(x => x.Key != default(int)).GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key).OrderByDescending(x => x.Sum(y => y.Value)).Select(x => x.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

Do you see any improvement / issue?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are not actually using a dictionary I find anonymous tuples would be much more readable here. Consider this where you don't even need a `List<T>` but just a simple array:

```
var weights = new (int RegionId, int Importance)[]
{
  (regionIdByIp, 5),
  (regionIdByPhone, 3),
  (regionIdByInput, 4)
};
```

Where you define such a tuple as `(int RegionId, int Importance)`. With it the next query (also written with line breaks) would be much easier to understand.

```
int mostImportantRegionId = 
    weights
        .Where(x => x.RegionId > 0)
        .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.RegionId)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Sum(y => y.Importance))
        .Select(x => x.RegionId)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

I also think that `x.Key != default(int)` is a strage condition. If `Key` is an id then it probably should be greater than `0` so it's better to write `x.RegionId > 0` instead.

---

What you also can do better is the `await` part. Currently you wait for each task to finish one-by-one. Let's them work in parallel with `WaitAll`:

```
var regionIdByIpTask = GetRegionIdByKeywordAsync(regionByIpStr);
var regionIdByPhoneTask = GetRegionIdByKeywordAsync(regionByPhoneStr);
var regionIdByInputTask = GetRegionIdByKeywordAsync(regionByInputStr);

Task.WaitAll(new [] 
{
    regionIdByIpTask,
    regionIdByPhoneTask,
    regionIdByInputTask
};
```

Now you can build your weights:

```
var weights = new (int RegionId, int Importance)[]
{
  (regionIdByIpTask.Result, 5),
  (regionIdByPhoneTask.Result, 3),
  (regionIdByInputTask.Result, 4)
};
```

Comment: No need to even `Task.WaitAll` - calling `.Result` [blocks until the async action is complete.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @EBrown yes, but you don't want to wait for one task at a time but for all of them at the same time. With `.Result` they will run one after another and not in parallel, won't they?

Comment: Not true: if the tasks have already started then calling `.Result` in sequence like that *effectively* has the same effect as calling `Task.WaitAll` because they need to finish, and if you call `.Result` on a *complete* task it returns immediately. If `Input` finishes first, great, but that doesn't help because we still need `Ip` to finish. Of course, now `Phone` is irrelevant (because it's a lower priority) so a more clever answer might utilize the priority to effectively cancel tasks that are now irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

As you're currently in an async method, you should also user `Task.WhenAll` to wait for these three sub tasks to finish asynchronously.

```
var regionIdByIpTask = GetRegionIdByKeywordAsync(regionByIpStr);
var regionIdByPhoneTask = GetRegionIdByKeywordAsync(regionByPhoneStr);
var regionIdByInputTask = GetRegionIdByKeywordAsync(regionByInputStr);

await Task.WhenAll(new [] 
{
    regionIdByIpTask,
    regionIdByPhoneTask,
    regionIdByInputTask
};
```

> **Task.WhenAll Method**
>
> Creates a task that will complete when all of the supplied tasks have completed.

*Source*: [msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

### Edit to clarify:

`Task.WaitAll` will actively wait for the completion of all sub tasks and thus block the current thread.

`Task.WhenAll` will return Task which can be awaited. Awaiting the task will "free" the current thread to process different tasks.

Comment: Haven't I already said that? :-]

Comment: You used `Task.WaitAll` which will block the current thread until all tasks are completed. `Task.WhenAll` will await all tasks to complete, so the Thread won't be blocked.

Comment: Oh, I see I cannot read, sorry ;-)

Comment: Yeah the calls are very similar. I've added a clarification to my awnser.

Answer (score 0):

I have just one point to add to those already made:

> ```
> .OrderByDescending(x => x.Sum(y => y.Value)).Select(x => x.Key).FirstOrDefault();
> ```

A full sort is overkill when the only element required is the largest. Finding largest elements by a projection is a relatively common operation. Both are good reasons for creating a `MaxBy` extension method (or using MoreLINQ's) - although here you really want

```
MaxByOrDefault(x => x.Sum(y => y.Value), x => x.Key)
```